# XigmaNAS: set different access rights to different SAMBA shares

Tags: network-shares, nas, samba

Here is what [XigmaNAS manual says](https://www.xigmanas.com/wiki/doku.php?id=faq:0045) regarding my question:

> Q: What do I need to do to setup different file / folder access for my
> Windows clients / users?
>
> A: If you carefully follow the basic steps
> covered in the latest Setup & User Guide 9.0.0.1 your CIFS/SMB server
> will be set-up so **everyone has read/write access without a password
> (Anonymous Authentication), this is fine for most people**.

Does it mean XigmaNAS is not even going to give different users different access rights on different shares it manages?

Quite strange position regarding a professional-grade piece of software. That's why I still hope I've just done poor search regarding my issue.

So, my question is: how to setup different access rights to different SAMBA shares for different users with XigmaNAS?

Thank you in advance.